# Magento 2.3 Migration - Centos 7 - Nginx - Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: migration, magento2.3.3, ssl

I just migrated my live Magento 1.9 to centos 7 - Nginx localhost, after migrated successfully i am getting the following error,

An error occurred during a connection to 192.168.1.64:8085. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

[image]

Not able to change the base URL:

[image]

Comment: Do you have SSL on localhost ?

Comment: @Pawan How to configure SSl in Centos 7 - Nginx

Comment: Shall i run this command : UPDATE core_config_data` SET value = '0' WHERE path = 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml'` and UPDATE core_config_data` SET value = '0' WHERE path = 'web/secure/use_in_frontend'`

Comment: it will remove force SSL and site will run without https

Comment: Sorry to ask this question, is it recommend or is it okay?

Comment: it is OK if run localhost without https, Please remove `var/cache` after run commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108789/discussion-between-zus-and-pawan).

Comment: run SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%theme%' and check id